# App crashes on Android after upgrading to the latest Titanium SDK

Tags: android, appcelerator, android-permissions, appcelerator-titanium

I was trying to upgrade my application to the latest Titanium SDK (5.2.2). It works fine on iOS but having some issues on Android. The app crashes after changing the SDK version.

The app uses camera, storage and locations. So, added the permissions for that. Here is a part of my tiapp.xml file for the same:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--CHANGE added package for iBeacon support for android -->
    <manifest android:versionCode="16" android:versionName="2.12" package="me.AppName.app">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>


        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
        <!-- Allows the API to download data from Google Map servers -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <!-- Allows the API to cache data -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <!-- Use GPS for device location -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <!-- Use Wi-Fi or mobile connection for device location -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <!-- Allows the API to access Google web-based services -->
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <!-- Specify OpenGL ES 2.0 as a requirement -->
        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
        <!-- Replace com.domain.appid with your application ID -->
        <uses-permission android:name="me.AppName.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <!--CHANGE permissions for iBeacon -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
        <!-- * -->
        <permission
            android:name="me.AppName.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar">
            <activity
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name=".AppNameActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <data android:scheme="AppName"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
            <activity
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar"/>
            <activity android:configChanges="screenSize" android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity"/>
            <activity
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="AppName"
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
            <activity android:label=“AppName”
                android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value=“SomeKey”/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
            <!--CHANGE added services for iBeacon support for android -->
            <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
                android:isolatedProcess="false"
                android:label="iBeacon" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service.IBeaconService"/>
            <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor">
                <meta-data android:name="background" android:value="true"/>
                <intent-filter android:priority="1">
                    <action android:name="me.AppName.app.DID_RANGING"/>
                    <action android:name="me.AppName.app.DID_MONITORING"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
            <!-- * -->
        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

This is a part of my logcat response:

`[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiFileHelper2.hasStoragePermission
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 33: Landroid/app/Activity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0017
[WARN] :   V8Object: (KrollRuntimeThread) [196,197] Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.media.MediaModule.hasCameraPermission
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 33: Landroid/app/Activity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.media.MediaModule.hasStoragePermission
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 33: Landroid/app/Activity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.media.MediaModule.hasCameraPermissions
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 33: Landroid/app/Activity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.media.MediaModule.requestCameraPermissions
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 88: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0037
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.filesystem.FilesystemModule.hasStoragePermissions
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 33: Landroid/app/Activity;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.filesystem.FilesystemModule.requestStoragePermissions
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 88: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0025
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.compression.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.compression.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.compression.so 0x4193fb00, skipping init
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libcom.liferay.beacons.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libcom.liferay.beacons.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libcom.liferay.beacons.so 0x4193fb00, skipping init
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.map.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.map.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.map.so 0x4193fb00, skipping init
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.barcode.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.barcode.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.barcode.so 0x4193fb00, skipping init
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.styledlabel.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.styledlabel.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libti.styledlabel.so 0x4193fb00, skipping init
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libfacebook.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libfacebook.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/libfacebook.so 0x4193fb00, skipping init
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/liborg.iotashan.TiTouchImageView.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/liborg.iotashan.TiTouchImageView.so 0x4193fb00
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/me.AppName.app-2/liborg.iotashan.TiTouchImageView.so 0x4193fb00, skipping init
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15187: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15191: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4331K, 32%% free 10408K/15164K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
[DEBUG] :  AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41661d40)`

What could be the possible problem here? Can anyone look around?

Thanks!

Comment: There are several (open) issues on [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22checkSelfPermission%22) mentioning `checkSelfPermission`. Could you see which one might be related, watch the ticket and add additional information and try possibly mentioned workarounds? I'd also try to remove the `<android>` section of your `tiapp.xml`, then do a clean build and see if that fixes it. Then only add back in to your `tiapp.xml` the elements which you see are not generated automatically in `build/android/AndroidManifest.xml` because you seem to have a lot of unneeded

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? For me, even when I am creating a  new application (just the auto generated code, no manual code), and try to run it on Android 4.0 device, then it gives the same issue.

Comment: Okay, so I started with the logs in reverse.

`[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
`

It was an issue related to themes. We must update the theme if we are upgrading from 4.0.0RC to 5.2.xGA version. Rest of the errors are same even now but the app doesn't crash.